# Asynchronous file upload with progress bar not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a file upload feature for my web application using JavaScript, and I'm trying to implement an asynchronous file upload with a progress bar to provide a better user experience. However, I'm encountering some issues and could use some guidance.

Here's what I have so far:

1. I have an HTML form with an input element of type "file" for selecting the file to upload.
2. On form submission, I'm using the Fetch API to send the file to the server asynchronously.
3. I'm listening to the "progress" event on the XMLHttpRequest object to track the upload progress and update a progress bar element on the page.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', (event) => {
    const percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    // Update the progress bar with the calculated percentage
    document.querySelector('.progress-bar').style.width = percent + '%';
  });
  
  xhr.open('POST', '/upload', true);
  xhr.send(formData);
});
```

The problem is that the progress bar is not updating as expected. It remains at 0% throughout the upload process and only jumps to 100% when the upload is complete.

I've checked the network tab in the browser's developer tools, and it shows that the file upload is indeed progressing. However, the progress bar doesn't reflect this.

Am I missing something in my code? How can I fix this issue and make the progress bar update correctly during the file upload process?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you check if your eventListener is called? Did you check your calculations? Also did you check if the [`event.lengthComputable === true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent/lengthComputable)? Otherwise it won't be possible to calculate a progress value